# How to check if a file is modified in Deno?

Tags: deno

Basically given a file `example.txt` and a time `t`, I want to know whether the version of that file at `t` is the same as the version now.

I need to know how to do this in order to perform cache invalidation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Deno.stat`](https://doc.deno.land/https/github.com/denoland/deno/releases/latest/download/lib.deno.d.ts#Deno.stat) and check `mtime`.

```js
const stat = await Deno.stat(filepath);
console.log(stat.mtime);
```

`.stat` requires `--allow-read` flag.