# Reading file size and last modified date for file using Deno

Tags: javascript, file, server, deno

How can I use Deno to read the size of a file and its last modified date/time?

In the browser I can use `instanceOfFile.size` and `instanceOfFile.lastModified` but these don't work if I provide the path to the file on the server.

```js
const file = '/home/test/data.json'
const isFile = await fileExists(file)
if (isFile) {
  console.log(file.size)          // returns `undefined`
  console.log(file.lastModified). // returns `undefined`
}
```

Comment: See the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62133271/how-to-check-if-a-file-is-modified-in-deno esp. "Deno.stat" and "Deno.FileInfo" https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.FileInfo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Deno.stat`](https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable#Deno.stat) for that.

```js
const file = await Deno.stat("/home/test/data.json");
if (file.isFile) {
  console.log("Last modified:", file.mtime?.toLocaleString());
  console.log("File size in bytes:", file.size);
}
```